# using sed to edit string at a specific position in a file

Tags: bash, sed

Given a file user.txt, I want to replace the username1 "john" with "michael".

Suppose the file contains the following data.

```
username1.user=john/password2.user=xyz
```

I want to search the file for the String "username1" and then replace the name john with michael. However john can appear more than once in the file while "username1" only appears once.

I was thinking if I could search for the String "username1.user=" using sed and then somehow edit the next characters to replace john with michael without changing any of the text after(so keeping "/password2.user=xyz" as same).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if username is unique

```
sed '/^username1\./{s/john/michael/}'
```

Comment: That would replace `johnson` with `michaelson`. idk if that'd be desirable or not, but I suspect not.

Answer (score 1):

To replace any name:

```
$ sed 's:^\(username1\.[^=]*=\)[^/]*:\1michael:' file
username1.user=michael/password2.user=xyz
```

To only replace if the name is john:

```
$ sed 's:^\(username1\.[^=]*=\)john:\1michael:' file
username1.user=michael/password2.user=xyz
```

Comment: Hi Ed, I'm using a mac terminal. It displays the output as required but the file is not saved with the name michael. What should i do?

Comment: `sed 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`